# How to point onclick event on a specific table row content using the id of the row and rel attribute of link - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table generated dynamically

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="address-row-2">
            <td><input type="text" value="com@com.com" id="email-1" class="email"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="John Doe 1" id="name-1" class="name"></td>
            <td>1 September 2013</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="orange" rel="edit-2">submit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="address-row-3">
            <td><input type="text" value="com@com.com" id="email-2" class="email"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="John Doe 2" id="name-2" class="name"></td>
            <td>2 September 2013</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="orange" rel="edit-3>submit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="address-row-4">
            <td><input type="text" value="com@com.com" id="email-3" class="email"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="John Doe 3" id="name-3" class="name"></td>
            <td>3 September 2013</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="orange" rel="edit-4>submit</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the submit button is used to make the inputs editable in order to change the content inline

```
$("input.email:text, input.name:text").attr("disabled",true);
$(".orange").attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)').click(function (){
    $("input.email:text, input.name:text").addClass("show-border");
    $("input.email:text, input.name:text").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

how ca I point the onclick event of the button to the inputs from it's row id.
To be more specific, If i click in the third row the submit button, I want to be able to edit only the inputs from the third row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse the DOM to find the elements relative to the clicked button. Try this:

```
$(".orange").attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)').click(function (){
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $("input.email, input.name", $row).addClass("show-border");
    $("input.email, input.name", $row).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9d6x2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just using `closest` to search up in the DOM:

```
$('input').click(function(){
    var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
});
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6uMjR/

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$(".orange").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("input:text").prop("disabled", false);
});
```